# A little question about the fact that $(\frac{1}{a_n}) \to +\infty$ given a certain condition

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $(a_n)$ is a null sequence and $a_n > 0$ for all $n \implies (\frac{1}{a_n}) \to +\infty$.
>
> Proof: For given $C$ there's some $N$ such that $n > N \implies |a_n| < \frac1C \implies 0 < a_n < 1/C \implies C < \frac{1}{a_n}$.

My question is what kind of $N$ did they choose to conclude $|a_n| < \frac1C$?

Comment: Since $a_n>0$, $|a_n|=a_n$. The rest follows from the formal definition of the expresion $\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\to +\infty$. Do you know it?

Comment: @user27454, everything makes sense(according to the definition of that expression), except I can't seem to find $N$ that makes $|a_n| < \frac1C$

Comment: Notice that all conditions $|a_n| < \frac1C$, $0 < a_n < 1/C $ and $C < \frac{1}{a_n}$ are equivalent because $C,a_n>0$.